# Image doesn't appear

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and I have this homework to do. The teacher asked us to display a greeting message to the user which should look like:

Good(Morning/Evening/Night), username, actual date(taken from the system).

**PHP:**

```
$username = "Foo";

if (date("H") > 0 && date("H") < 12) {
    $msg = "Good day";
    $image = "r_sun";
}
else if (date("H") >= 12 && date("H") < 18) {
    $msg = "Good evening";
    $image = "sun";
}
else {
    $msg = "Good Night";
    $image = "moon";
}

if (date("d") == 1) {
    $c = "st";
} 
else if (date("d") == 2) {
    $c = "nd";
}
else if (date("d") == 3) {
    $c = "rd";
}
else {
    $c = "th";
}

echo $msg . "<img src='images/" . $image . ".png' border='0' />, " . $username . "! Today is " . date("F") . " " . date("d") . $c . ", " . date("Y");
```

My problem is with the image. I have to show 3 different images depending on which message is being displayed (Good morning, evening or night). For some reason the image won't load on the page.

Comment: Does the directory `image` is in the same as the file and the names of the images are ok?

Comment: hey, is the image exist in your folder?

Comment: my code is on the path www/admin and the images are in www/images. this is problem? yes they exists!

Comment: I would try doing an echo of the $image variable before the img tag, to be sure that you are getting the right info in the variable first. Also, I would be sure that your images are located in "images" folder, and you might need to put a "/" (slash) before the images folder, depending on the server configuration you are using.

Comment: if your script is at www/admin, you should be access the URL like /admin/FILE.php, and your image should be /images/IMG.png

Comment: The server is looking for the image in `www/admin/images/`. You might want to move your images there, or in the code, reference the image as `../images/`

Comment: @VoteMeUp if your images are in a higher folder level you need to use "../" in this case ../images/foo.png

Comment: I would use firebug or the developer toolbar, or viewing the source of the page, to check how the img tag is formed. Try copying and pasting the src into your browser to make sure the image is there :)

Comment: Thank you guys, i think he passed this paths to confuse indeed. now i understand what to do with the paths. thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `../` before the `images` path on your `src` attribute like this:

```
<img src='../images/" . $image . ".png' border='0' />
```

This means that your `image` path is not on the same directory as your script, like you doing.

Plus, just a tip, place the `date` values on an variable:

```
$h = date("H");
$d = date("d");

if ($h > 0 && $h < 12) {
    $msg = "Good day";
    $image = "r_sun";
}

if ($d== 1) {
    $c = "st";
}
```

Will clear your code ;)

Comment: great! thank you, that worked like a charm and i done what you sayd about the variables, it's better indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above:

> my code is on the path www/admin and the images are in www/images

It sounds like the `img` tag just needs a slight adjustment.  Try this:

```
echo $msg . "<img src='../images/" . $image . ".png' border='0' />, " . $username . "! Today is " . date("F") . " " . date("d") . $c . ", " . date("Y");
```

The key difference is adding the `../` to the start of the path.  This is a [relative path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) designation which tells the browser to go up one directory before looking for the path/file specified.

Note that this isn't an issue with the PHP code specifically.  The code was correctly emitting a valid `img` tag.  The problem was that the path was pointing to a file that doesn't exist (`www/admin/images/filename`) instead of one that does (`www/images/filename`).

Answer (score 0):

The way you've specified your img src, the `images` must exist in the same directory as your script (or your `basehref` if you've set that in the html head).  Check that first.

Secondly, check the permissions of the `images` directory. It must be at least world-executable (0711).

Thirdly, check the permissions of the image files. They must be at least world-readable (0644).

Comment: thank you for your information but it was not my problem since i'm running a local web server on uniform server, i think. thank you .